# How to add value to checkedListBox items

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

Is it possible to add to `checkedListBox` item also value and title

```
checkedListBox1.Items.Insert(0,"title");
```

How to add also value?

Answer (score 9):

```
checkedListBox1.Items.Insert(0, new ListBoxItem("text", "value"));
```

Comment: sorry for question, what is ListItem in this case?

Comment: I have error 
The type or namespace name 'ListItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: try this: ListBoxItem("text", "value") instead of ListItem("text", "value")

Comment: I can't find any "ListBoxItem" class in Winforms, only in WPF...

Answer (score 8):

Try setting the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties.  Then you can pass an anonymous object like so:

```
checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
checkedListBox1.Items.Insert(0, new { Text= "text", Value = "value"})
```

**Edit**:

To answer your question below, you can create a class for your item like so:

```
public class MyListBoxItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And then add them like this:

```
checkedListBox1.Items.Insert(0, new MyListBoxItem { Text = "text", Value = "value" });
```

And then you can get the value like this:

```
(checkedListBox1.Items[0] as MyListBoxItem).Value
```

Comment: how to get this valueMeber and Display member

foreach (object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
????
}

Comment: P.S:
You need to override ToString() method in MyListBoxItem class. CheckListBox will call your ToString() method.